# Is it possible to decrease the loadtime of a single post with a lot of categories in the WordPress backend?

Tags: wordpress, caching, load, admin

Hi at the moment I have more than 4000 categories in my WordPress database. Every time when I want to add or edit a post in the backend it opens very slow and has a delay before I can edit the post. I understand that it is a lot of work to reload all those categories every time I open a post. My question is if there is a solution to decrease the loading time in this situation?

Or perhaps are there any cache plugins voor the WordPress backend?

The memory limit in php.ini is already set to the max amount.

Comment: Most caching plugins don't really do anything for the admin side.  That's a massive number of categories.  The issue is almost certainly that it's a simply a large amount of data / HTML the browser has to render with that number of categories.  I'm surprised you aren't running into issues with MAX_INPUT_VARS with that number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking a look at this site. It may or may not help with the admin side of WP, but its worth a try. http://www.sparringmind.com/speed-up-wordpress/This excerpt specifically: "You can simply use the WP-Optimize plugin, which I run on all of my sites.

This plugin lets you do just one simple task: optimize the your database (spam, post revisions, drafts, tables, etc.) to reduce their overhead.

I would also recommend the WP-DB Manager plugin, which can schedule dates for database optimization."